# How do I go about correcting numbers in my accepted conference paper?

Tags: publications, errors-erratum

I have submitted a working paper to a conference. The working paper was accepted and I was asked to submit the final version.
During further data analysis I noticed a small error in my code (calculation of a variable), that affects path coefficients and model fit statistics. The incorrect values are only slightly off, so none of the results change.
Should I just change the values in the final submission or should I contact the editor beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

Just make the necessary corrections. Only a major glitch calling the conclusions into question would warrant anything more. Small changes are pretty common in such things.